# Declaring generic variables with complex class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class to calculate with complex numbers, a real part and an imaginary part as double type.
In other part I have a rational class to calculate rational numbers.
Now I want that my complex class can operate when the real part and the imaginary part are rational numbers. I've read some docs about generics but I don't know how to declare real part and imaginary part as generic types and use methods as add 2 complex numbers when the real and imaginary parts are doubles or rationals.
This is my test code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Complex {
    private double real;
    private double imaginary;
    private Rational qreal;
    private Rational qimaginary;

    public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
        super();
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }
    public Complex(Rational real, Rational imaginary) {
        this.qreal = real;
        this.qimaginary = imaginary;
    }
    public Complex(String z) {
        z = z.replaceAll(" ","");
        if(z.contains("i") || z.contains("j")){
            if(z.contains("+")) {
                String[] z1 = z.split(Pattern.quote("+"));
                this.real = Double.parseDouble(z1[0]);
                this.imaginary = Double.parseDouble(z1[1].substring(0, z1.length-1));
            }
            else if(z.contains("-")) {
                String[] z1 = z.split(Pattern.quote("-"));
                this.real = Double.parseDouble(z1[0]);
                this.imaginary = -Double.parseDouble(z1[1].substring(0, z1.length-1));
            }
            else System.out.println("Syntax Error");
        }
        else System.out.println("The complex must only contains i or j as imaginary unit");
    }
    public double getReal() {
        return real;
    }
    public void setReal(double real) {
        this.real = real;
    }
    public double getImaginary() {
        return imaginary;
    }
    public Rational getQreal() {
        return qreal;
    }
    public void setQreal(Rational qreal) {
        this.qreal = qreal;
    }
    public Rational getQimaginary() {
        return qimaginary;
    }
    public void setQimaginary(Rational qimaginary) {
        this.qimaginary = qimaginary;
    }
    public void setImaginary(double imaginary) {
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    Complex opposite(Complex z) {return new Complex(-z.real, -z.imaginary);}
    double abs() {return Math.hypot(this.real, this.imaginary);}
    Complex conjugate() {return new Complex(real, -imaginary);}
    Complex inverse() {
        if(this.real == 0 && this.imaginary == 0) return new Complex(Double.NaN, Double.NaN);
        else {
            Complex c = this.conjugate();
            double abs_square = Math.pow(this.abs(), 2.);
            return new Complex(c.real / abs_square, c.imaginary / abs_square);
        }
    }

    Complex add2(Complex z) {
        System.out.println("Suma " + this.qreal.add(z.qreal) + " " + this.qimaginary.add(z.qimaginary) + "i");
        return new Complex(this.qreal.add(z.qreal), this.qimaginary.add(z.qimaginary));
    }
    Complex add(Complex z) {return new Complex(this.real + z.real, this.imaginary + z.imaginary);}
    Complex subtract(Complex z) {return add(z.opposite(z));}
    Complex product(Complex z) {
        double r, i;
        r = this.real * z.real - this.imaginary * z.imaginary;
        i = this.real * z.imaginary + this.imaginary * z.real;
        return new Complex(r, i);
    }
    Complex div(Complex z) {
        Complex num = this.product(z.conjugate());
        double den = Math.pow(Math.hypot(z.real, z.imaginary), 2.);
        return new Complex(num.real / den, num.imaginary / den);
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Complex [real=" + real + ", imaginary=" + imaginary + ", qreal=" + qreal + ", qimaginary=" + qimaginary
                + "]";
    }


    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
        if(imaginary > 0.) {
            if (imaginary == 1.)
                return real + " + " + "i";
            return real + " + " + imaginary + "i";
        }
        else if(imaginary < 0.) {
            if (imaginary == -1.)
                return real + " - " + "i";
            return real + " " + imaginary + "i";
        }
        else if(imaginary == 0.)
            return "" +  real;
        else if(real == 0.)
            return  imaginary + "i";
        else
            return "0";
    }*/



}
```

If you see the code I've implemented 2 add methods but i want only one,and so that for the other methods, toString() too.

Comment: Unrelated: you want to read about "Clean Code" (for example the great book by Robert Martin), and more specifically: about "single layer of abstraction" principle. Your code could benefit from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are useful when you want to preserve type information. But the generic type still needs to have some known interface in order to use it. Since `double` and `Rational` don't share common interface, it will not be possible to directly create a generic implementation that works for both types.

What you could do is create an interface `Complex` with 2 implementations, `DoubleComplex` and `RationalComplex`:

```
public interface Complex<T> {

    T getReal();
    T getImaginary();

    Complex<T> opposite(Complex<T> z);
    double abs();
    Complex<T> conjugate();
    Complex<T> inverse();

    Complex<T> add(Complex<T> z);
    Complex<T> subtract(Complex<T> z);
    Complex<T> product(Complex<T> z);
    Complex<T> div(Complex<T> z);

}

public class DoubleComplex implements Complex<Double> {

    private final double real;
    private final double imaginary;

    ...

    @Override
    public Complex<Double> add(Complex<Double> z) {
        return new DoubleComplex(this.real + z.getReal(), this.imaginary + z.getImaginary());
    }

    ...
}

public class RationalComplex implements Complex<Rational> {

    private final Rational real;
    private final Rational imaginary;

    ...

    @Override
    public Complex<Rational> add(Complex<Rational> z) {
        return new RationalComplex(this.real.add(z.getReal()), this.imaginary.add(z.getImaginary()));
    }

    ...
}
```